# Ubuntu brightness issue

Tags: 12.04, samsung

I used to set the brightness in low level and ma icons size to small. But whenever I reboot, it set the default brightness and icons size. Icon size I managee but I have to set the brightness to low everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Go to startup Applications in the dash.
Add a new startup program "Brightness Level" and add in the command line:
xbacklight -set XX
XX being the level you wan at boot. I think it's a 100 scale. I've set mine at 60.
Best,

Comment: it didnt help dude :(